# Getting the first value from this string and convert it to an integer

Tags: c

```
"123456\000\";\"Bilka\";\"Tilst afdelingen\";\"Ager\370vej 7\";\"Port 39\";\"8381\";\"Tilst\";\"25\";\"100\";\"125\";\"90\";\"Phi"
```

I need to get the first 123456 and store it as an int, how can i do this?

Comment: The problem description is incomplete. Do you need to parse just this one line and once? Do you need to parse many such lines? Do you know if the number will change or will it always be 6 digits? Show us some code you've written.

Comment: Your description isn't entirely clear. Is this intended to be a C string literal, or is it (for example) a string as it comes in from the outside world, so the `\0' is really two characters, a backslash and a digit 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sscanf()`.

```
char *str = "123456\000\";\"Bilka\";\"Tilst afdelingen\";\"Ager\370vej 7\";\"Port 39\";\"8381\";\"Tilst\";\"25\";\"100\";\"125\";\"90\";\"Phi";
int num = 0;

sscanf(str, "%d", &num);
printf(" The extracted number is %d.\n", num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [atoi(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)

```
int n = atoi("123456\000\";\"Bilka\";\"Tilst afdelingen\";\"Ager\370vej 7\";\"Port 39\";\"8381\";\"Tilst\";\"25\";\"100\";\"125\";\"90\";\"Phi"
```

);

Answer (score 1):

Use strtol(), it does better error reporting than atoi().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `atoi` or the below program.. However the below one is not advised as it is not portable and makes an assumption that the machine uses `acsii` character set.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int atoi_1(char a[])
{
    int n=0;

    if (a[0] >= '0' && a[0] <= '9') {
        n = a[0]-'0';
    } else {
        /* exception - a[0] is not an integer */
        printf("exception - a[0] is not an integer \n");
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "123456\000\";\"Bilka\";\"Tilst afdelingen\";\"Ager\370vej 7\";\"Port 39\";\"8381\";\"Tilst\";\"25\";\"100\";\"125\";\"90\";\"Phi";

    printf("a[0] = %d \n", atoi_1(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc atoi.c 
$ ./a.out 
a[0] = 1 
$
```

Comment: Use `isdigit` instead of the '0' - '9' range based checks.

Comment: will also work for `EBCDIC`. However, I have no idea why anyone would not use `isdigit`.